# What value of capacitor is ck3?

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

all. Anyone know what value this capacitor should be? It says 104... but that does not help. 
[image]

Comment: The value "104" means \$10 \times 10^4 = 100000\$ This is in pF so 100nF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

104 means 10 with 4 zeros.  Measured in picofarads.
So 100000pF or 100nF or 0.1uF

103 would be 10 with 3 zeros - 10000pF or 10nF or 0.01uF

Comment: Ah makes sense. Thanks HandyHowie

Answer (score 1):

That "104" notation is similar to the resistor colour code - it gives the first two digits of the value, then the number of zeros to give the value in picofarads.

If you want to buy a 0.1 uF capacitor, the manufacturer's part number will probably have "104" in it somewhere, but I consider it very bad practice to use that code on schematics.

(If they use "104" for the capacitor, why don't they use "102" for the 1K resistor, to be consistent?)

Comment: Thank you and Good point. The schematics I am referencing are not the best. Lots of inconsistencies and missing passive components.

Answer (score -2):

That is the value: 100000 pF or 100 nF.

Comment: Can you please explain how you are able to tell?

Comment: Many years of experience. It can't really be anything else.